# What would make comments on post disappear?

Tags: support

Last night I had 3 or 4 comments on a post I made at the URL:

[How To Get Url Parameter Routing Working in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41927904/how-to-get-url-parameter-routing-working-in-asp-net-core)

Now, when I go back to that question, the short discussion is gone.  Did someone delete them? They were completely appropriate questions relative to my question.

Answer (score 2):

[Comments are second-class citizen, and once they have served their purpose, they are likely to be deleted.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment)

- Do not post *critical* information related to the post in comments, improve the post / formulate an answer thereof.
- Do not *expect* the comments to hang around forever, there are explicit flags to get them removed.

Comment: Again, what makes them disappear? does a senior SO person choose? do they get downvoted? i don't see that answer @Servy.  How are you meant to get clarification on an answer that may be partially correct or incomplete?

Comment: @PeterKellner many things, like 1) flagged as obsolete 2) flagged as too chatty 3) flagged as not constructive. Also, extended discussions in comments are likely to be moved to chat.

Comment: @Servy well, there is one more thing and that's if the answer that I had commented on was removed, then so went it comments.  The person who answered my question must have recognized that my question pointed out his wrong answer so he replaced it with a different answer without saying anything.  I didn't bother to re-read the answer because I thought I had read it already.